# Exception raised during rendering: 16 (Details)

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

preview in Android Studio doesn't work.
Tried to change API, but without results.

> Exception raised during rendering: 16 (Details)

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 16
    at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:854)
    at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:603)
    at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:50)
    at android.text.StaticLayout$Builder.build(StaticLayout.java:425)
    at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:8272)
    at android.widget.TextView.assumeLayout(TextView.java:8104)
    at android.widget.TextView.onPreDraw(TextView.java:6742)
    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:977)
    at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.dispatchOnPreDraw(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:46)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(RenderSessionImpl.java:404)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(RenderSessionImpl.java:543)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:426)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.BridgeRenderSession.render(BridgeRenderSession.java:108)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:154)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:136)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$renderInner$5(RenderTask.java:671)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: add more details about error and code segment please

Comment: share your code

Comment: try to build by putting <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> in style.xml replacing current one

Comment: @Lucefer Nothing happened, still blank view

Comment: try solution which is given for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047172/android-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-length-10-index-10

Comment: @Lucefer i deleted hints and that worked for me

Comment: Ok. Nice to hear it

Comment: If hint delete worked for u. Try to minimize character count of those hints without removing it. I think it will work for u as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in my custom view with `TextInputEditText` field (btw it was `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText`).

There was problem with `android:hint="@string/long_hint_descr"`. You removed a couple of words from `string.xml` for `long_hint_descr` and error was gone.

But easiest way is to add `tools:hint="short hint"` with short string and keep original long in strings.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this error.

In this case, I did the following:

On Android Studio: 
File ---> Invalidate Caches/ Restart...